# Using AJAX in login procedure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I just changed my login file **login.php** to a website I am building, as to apply AJAX inside it just to keep username and password visible in case of fault. In case of success I am using javascript

```
window.location = 'index.php';
```

as to redirect the user to the right place.

In my previous login file I did not use AJAX and the form submission was just calling the same login file. The last method was not keeping username and password and also I was using PHP

```
include "index.php";
```

as to redirect the user to the right place.

However, there is something I do not like with the first method. The transition from the login form to index.php is not smooth as it is with the second method and the screen seems first to reload login.php instantly and then go to index.php. Do you have any explanation or any solution as to eliminate this little flicker?

I am using the Jquery form plugin. It follows ***login.php***

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('#user_login_form').ajaxForm({    
        dataType:  'json', 
        success:   processJson           
    });
  });

function processJson(data) { 
    if (data=="database problem")
    {               
       ...             
       return;
    }
    if (data=="no member")
    {
       ...            
       return;  
    }
    window.location = 'index.php';
  }

 <form action="login_user_authorization.php" method="post" name="user_login_form" id="user_login_form" onsubmit="return validate_login_user()">      
   <input name="user_email" type="text" id="user_email"/> 
   <input name="user_password" id="user_password" type="password" />      
   <input type="submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button"  value="ENTER" />    
</form>
```

Comment: `creen seems first to reload login.php instantly and then go to index.php` I dont agree ... it should be smooth ... post your full code .

Comment: You gave me the idea. I have to add exit; after window.location for there is HTML code underneath.